# How to estimate the density (empirical pdf) from quantiles (the empirical CDF) in R

Tags: r, simulation, sampling, montecarlo

#### Question

Say I have an unknown density `a`.

All I know is a probability grid (`probs`) of quantiles (`quants`).

How can I generate random samples from the unknown density?

#### This is what I have so far.

I am giving rejection sampling a try, but I am not tied to this method. Here I fit a polynomial (6 degress) to the quantiles. The purpose of this is to convert discrete quantiles to a smooth continuous function. This gives me an empirical CDF. I then use rejection sampling to get actual samples from the CDF. Is there a convenient way in R to convert samples from the CDF to density samples, or did I go about this in a convoluted way when there is a better alternative?

```
# unknown and probably not normal, but I use rnorm here because it is easy
a <- c(exp(rnorm(200, 5, .8)))
probs <- seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05)
quants <- quantile(a, probs)
df_quants <- tibble::tibble(cum_probs, quants)
df_quants <- df_quants
fit <- lm(quants ~ poly(cum_probs, 6), df_quants)
df_quants$fit <- predict(fit, df_quants)

p <- df_quants %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cum_probs, y = quants))+
  geom_line(aes(y = quants), color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit), color = "red", size = 1)
```

### CDF

[image: cdf]

```
count = 1
accept = c()
X <- runif(50000, 0, 1)
U <- runif(50000, 0, 1)
estimate <- function(x){
  new_x <- predict(fit, data.frame(cum_probs = c(x)))
  return(new_x)
while(count <= 50000 & length(accept) < 40000){
  test_u = U[count]
  test_x = estimate(X[count])/(1000*dunif(X[count], 0, 1))
  if(test_u <= test_x){
    accept = rbind(accept, X[count])
    count = count + 1
  }
    count = count + 1
}
p2 <- as_tibble(accept, name = V1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V1)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 45)
}
```

## CDF Samples

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rejection sampling is needed, with a Bspline fit I was able to generate sensible samples via Inverse Transform, but I also needed a higher resolution grid. The tails are a little off.

The assumption I am making here is that a Bspline fit to a tight grid of quantiles approximate the inverse CDF function. Once this curve is fut I can just use random uniforms `U[0,1]`

```
library(splines2)

a <- c(exp(rnorm(200, 5, .8)))
cum_probs <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
quants <- quantile(a, cum_probs)
df_quants <- tibble::tibble(cum_probs, quants)
fit_spline <- lm(quants ~ bSpline(cum_probs, df = 9), df_quants)
df_quants$fit_spline <- predict(fit_spline, df_quants)
estimate <- function(x){
  new_x <- predict(fit_spline, data.frame(cum_probs = c(x)))
  return(new_x)
}
e <- runif(10000, 0, 1)
y <-(estimate(e))
df_density <- tibble(y)
df_densitya <- tibble(a)
py <- df_density %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = y)) +
  geom_histogram()
pa <- df_densitya %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = a)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 45)
```

#### original density

[image]

#### Inverse Transformation samples

[image]

#### summary stats

original dist `a`

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
20.36   80.84  145.25  195.72  241.22 1285.24
```

generated from quantiles `y`

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
28.09   81.78  149.53  189.07  239.62  667.27
```